# Anything such as a usb laptop charger?

Tags: laptop, usb, charger

I am looking for a laptop charger that requires no power outlet but instead utilizes a usb port of another computer to charge my laptop. That is, I am seeking a usb-to-laptop port charger, NOT power outlet-to-laptop's usb charger. Is such a product even possible? I am guessing no since the usb port would not be able to supply enough electricity to power the laptop, even to maintain the battery (not charge it).

Comment: IIRC, you can tricklecharge the new HP chromebook off a USB port. It does come with a specific, high current charger for proper use though

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in the last part - a USB port will never output enough power to get a laptop going. Most laptops are around 18 volts, and the maximum a USB port will put out is 5 volts. An average laptop is around 18 volts (65 watts or so) and upwards from there. (Mine is 85 actually).

**tl;dr version: No.**

Comment: *"around 18 volts of power"* -- Volts are not a measure of power. Watts are a measure of power.  Volts measure electromotive force.  Force is not the same as power (in physics).

Comment: @sawdust fixed it to make it a bit more scientifically correct

Comment: This answer is out of date. USB 3.1 can produce up to 100W and will be a new standard for DC power in a household. The HP Chromebook 11 is powered by USB. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_3.1

Answer (score 3):

Converting 5 Volts to 18 (or 24, or...) Volts is quite possible, but to pull 65 watts (much less 85, much less adding conversion losses) from USB's 5 volts would require getting 13 Amperes (current) from the USB port, and THAT you won't find anytime soon, if ever. Some of the high-current special jobs go to 2 Amps (10Watts @ 5Volts), stock is 500 mA (2.5 W) direct-connect, 100 mA (500mW) from older keyboards or unpowered hubs.

Answer (score 0):

It is not practical, but the voltage conversion would work but would have so few milli-amps that it would not charge.  It might extended the life span by 10-30min if the laptop was super low power.

Watch for USB 3.1  I recently read an article.
[New USB specs 3.1](http://blog.laptopmag.com/usb-31-demo-speed)

According to several articles 3.1 provides up to 100 watts of power.
You could charge a laptop slooowly with that much power.

100w @ 5v is roughly 25w @20v

Comment: no, 100W at 5V is roughly 85-95 W at 20V depending on how good the guy making the dc-dc converter is.

Answer (score 0):

USB 3.1 is now capable of supporting the necessary wattage for notebooks/chromebooks/etc. Chromebooks are a convenient application for this because they now use a USB-C connector for charging.

The 12V at 5A setting is safer to use, but you could set the USB3.1 port to use the 20V at 5A setting if you wanted a quicker charge.

I have not tried this but it is theoretically possible.

Comment: This doesn't really address the constraints in the question.  If you had a device that could charge via USB at those settings, and if you had a USB 3.1 charger that provided those outputs, and if the device was designed to handshake with the charger to accept those settings, then yes, you could charge that way.  However, the question asks about charging from a computer USB port.  Computer USB ports aren't designed for charging devices at those levels.

Comment: I agree that I am being overly speculative. Running 100W within a motherboard bus is unlikely to ever be practical or safe for a consumer motherboard. There are already motherboards that can be configured to output 12V at lower amperage through USB3.1 ports, so that would be a more realistic answer.